# What way to change Hash back to it string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I am writing a part of code to change string into hash

```
String hash = GetHashString("A"); //return 7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29
```

My question is how can I get back "A" when I pass in the hash code  ?

> 7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29

Comment: Hashes are intended to be a one way transformation.

Comment: Hashes aren't reversible. If you want something reversible, you're looking for an encoding. Without knowing what your `GetHashString` method actually does, there's no way to know if it's one or the other, but if it's correctly named, it would be a one way operation.

Comment: That's the MD5 hash. It is not designed to be a reversible operation. Of course, it is very weak at this point and many people have created lookups to reverse it. Just googling the value will give you several websites that can reverse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are not meant to be reversible. If you want to compare its origin with another string, just hash the second one too and then compare their hashes.

Comment: Hi @Mihai Caracostea , I want to use the original value and do not want others to know the value. Any recommendation ?

Comment: Consider this: if you could reverse the transformation, then anyone could also. So there would be no more security in storing, say, passwords as hashes. Your best bet would be encryption instead of hashing.